# How to change client listening address in etcd

Tags: etcd

I have installed a product called Apache APisix, on a Centos 8 vm, which uses etcd to store data.

When I run a command like etcdctl member list, the listening ip address is 127.0.0.1. This is a problem as I want to be able to connect to etcd from a remote server.

I am having some trouble figuring out how to change the client/listening ips of etcd. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Tried etcd member update, and passing various arguments.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the conf/config.yaml file in a text editor.
2. Locate the etcd section in the file.
3. Modify the host field to the new etcd connection address. If there are multiple etcd hosts, you can define them as a list.
4. Save the changes to the file.

```yaml
etcd:
    host:
      - "https://10.10.100.74:2379"
    prefix: "/apisix"
```

5. Reload APISIX using: `apisix reload`